# Where is gmock_gen.py script

Tags: googletest, googlemock

I remember that some time ago there was a python script in gtest repository (https://github.com/google/googletest) to generate a mock class automatically. But I can't find it anymore in newer releases. Does Google still support it? Any idea where can I find the recent version of that script?

Comment: Can't find the official release on google. Found only mirrors in some private repos.

Comment: What do you mean by private repos? If you find the script, the repos are public. Also you haven't mentioned the official repo requirement in the question. Then look for it in the official tepo history.

Comment: GTest a few years ago added a new macro for creating methods inside a mock class. So instead of:

    MOCK_METHOD1(GetPair, std::pair<bool, int>(int));

we can use the following syntax:

    MOCK_METHOD((std::pair<bool, int>), GetPair, (int));

  
The generator I have generates the first version. I assume that the newest GTest generator would create the second version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is alive in the version 1.11.0
[googlemock/scripts/generator](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/release-1.11.0/googlemock/scripts/generator). It supports new `MOCK_METHOD`: [googlemock/scripts/generator/cpp/gmock_class.py:140](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.11.0/googlemock/scripts/generator/cpp/gmock_class.py#L140)

It was removed by Google from 1.12.0 on Sep 14, 2021.